# String becomes empty in an Arduino SPI transfer code

Tags: c++, string, arduino, spi

I'm new to Arduino and I'm trying to transfer data using SPI from one Arduino to another. I'm having a problem with sending an array of characters (C string). First, I think the problem is in defining the string itself (since I tried to serially print it on the same Arduino and it did work), all other datatypes get sent normally, but strings become blank for some reason (when I serially print them, an empty line is printed instead.

Here's the code for the master, the same problem is with the slave code.

```
// master
#include <SPI.h>
#include "SPI_anything.h"

// create a structure to store the different data values:
typedef struct myStruct {
  char cmd[4];
  double b;
  long c;
};

myStruct sent;
myStruct recieved;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin ();
  // Slow down the master a bit
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16);
  sent.cmd[4] = "def";
  sent.b = 32.2;
  sent.c = 100000;
}  // end of setup

void loop ()  { 
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);    // SS is pin 10
  // SPI_writeAnything (sent);
  delay(20);
  Serial.println (SPI_readAnything (recieved));
  String command=recieved.cmd;
  Serial.println (recieved.cmd);///////////
  Serial.println (sent.cmd);/////////////
  Serial.println (command);
  Serial.println (recieved.b);
  Serial.println (recieved.c);
  Serial.println ();
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  delay (1000);  // for testing  
  sent.c++;
}  // end of loop
```

In the monitor, `b` and `c` are printed normally (the are the data coming from the slave), but `cmd` is printed as an empty line (both the received and the sent).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: C != C++. Tag with only one for the language you're using.

Comment: I think it's better you change `sent.cmd[4]="def"` with `strcpy(send.cmd, "def")`. The instruction you coded assigns the value of the pointer that points `"def"` to the 5th char of a char-array that contains up to 4 bytes. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serge Ballesta pointed out the problem: you set the fourth element of the `cmd` array to the value of a pointer to a string, which is not what you intended to do.

Instead, you can initialize the structure at the same time as it is declared, as in the following example (it is not explicit Arduino code, but C/C++ compatible).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct myStruct {
  char cmd[4];
  double b;
  long c;
} myStruct;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  myStruct s = {
    "def", 3.0, 10000
  };
  printf("{%s, %f, %li}", s.cmd, s.b, s.c);
  return 0;
}
```

Saving this to a file `structTest.c`, compiling and running:

```
$ gcc structTest.c -o structTest
$ ./structTest.exe
{def, 3.000000, 10000}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the String type instead of char[] ?

The reason that double and long work is they point to a single reference. cmd points to an array of 4 references. If it works with string, it might be how you are handling the reading/printing of the char array. If you are concerned with the memory issues, use char* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Warnings are not meant to be ignored!

This line `sent.cmd[4] = "def";` is terrible. You declared `cmd` to be an array of 4 characters and you try to write a pointer to a litteral string in its 5th character! That may not be what you intented to do, but that's what a compiler will try to do...

The correct way is to *copy* C-strings:

```
strncpy(sent.cmd, "def", 4);
```

Alternatively you could use a C++ `std::string` that supports assignation, but uses dynamic memory so it may or not be an option in your use case.

BTW, C and C++ are different languages, with only a common subset. Writing code correct in both C and C++ in hardly if any possible, so please pick one.